# Handle multiple "windows" in Windows Store apps in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps, multitasking, windows-8.1

Ok, I have a question to which, despite my best efforts, I have not been able to solve. I searched the internet, and this is one of those that is particularly difficult to search for, but it seems that no user of Windows 8.1 nor any developers developing for Windows 8.1 has posted to any website asking how to do this (I could be wrong, of course).

What I am trying to do is make a Windows Store app targeting Windows 8.1, that takes advantage of multiple Windows. To see what I mean, open up metro ie, right click on a tab, and click "open in new window." This is also in the mail app, where you can open a single message in another window, which behaves like a separate app, and can be snapped like so. It's a new feature of the Windows 8.1 OS.

But I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it in C# and XAML. Does anyone know how? Thanks.

Alex

Answer (score 3):

There are new APIs in Windows.UI.ViewManagement, namely the [ApplicationViewSwitcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationviewswitcher.aspx) and [ProjectionManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.projectionmanager.aspx) classes. The former is for working with multiple independent views that the user can arrange side by side on whatever monitors they have, which is what IE and Mail use; the latter is for working with multiple monitors.

See the [Application Views sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Application-Views-98825022) along with the [Projection sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Projection-sample-526b3c1d) for working both scenarios in code.

Comment: Ok, I see, but how do you actually make a new window? There are no public constructors anywhere, the sample doesn't demonstrate it, and the only methods I can see are to work with existing windows and not to make new ones.

Comment: Never mind, the projection sample has it. Thank you!

Comment: It's MSApp.createNewView, for others who might read this post. Stuff can hide out in the MSApp object, as this is where app host specific APIs exist rather than in WinRT.

Answer (score 0):

Might be bit late with my answer, nevertheless I had your similar apprehensions about the "Dismal Support Refs" for this subject, when I first began searching the topic. However I have been able to overcome this and use the feature in my apps. There are some good refs available; The Windows Dev Centre has a Quickstart ie "Quiskstart Creating Multiple Windows", a Good guide is the "MultipleViews" Sample, With the following providing additional support.
1) "Be two places at once using multiple windows" at
https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/01/09/be-two-places-at-once-using-multiple-windows/#pBHiQtDSPFrCA7Gv.97

2) "MultipleViews for Windows 8.1 apps" (parts 1-3)
http://www.kraigbrockschmidt.com/2013/11/21/multiple-views-creating-view/

```
                                                           BQ at WATERVIEW
```